# dplyr: grouping and conditionally filtering

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering

My data consists of people.
They are labeled by profession and by Gender.
I want to filter out professions that do not have at least 5 females and 5 males.
This seems straightforward but I haven't managed to find a similar example on StackOverflow.

This is my attempt:

```
group_cols <- c("professions", "sex")

df %>%
  group_by(across(all_of(group_cols))) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  filter(n > 4) %>%
  summarize(n())
```

However, this gives me professions for which there are at least 5 females or 5 males.
I need to create a conditional rule that takes into account females and males for each profession, not separately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep `profession` that have at least 5 males and 5 females in the data you can use -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(profession) %>%
  filter(sum(sex == 'male', na.rm = TRUE) > 4 && 
         sum(sex == 'female', na.rm = TRUE) > 4) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Very elegant, Sir! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let assume there are 2 female workers, 2 male workers, 2 male students, 1 female student and 3 male developers. I understand that you would like to drop the "student" profession and the "developer" profession because there is not both at least 2 males and 2 females in these professions.

You can proceed in two steps:
**(1)** For each profession, count the minimum of male and female workers.
**(2)** Merge the dataframe and filter based on this minimum.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- as_tibble(
  data.frame(
    id=1:9,
    sex=c("F", "F", "F", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H", "H"),
    profession=c("worker","worker","student", "worker", "worker", "student", "developer", "developer", "developer")
    )
)

gb_cols <- c("profession", "sex")

agg <- data %>% group_by(across(all_of(gb_cols))) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols=profession,
    names_from=sex,
    values_from=n,
    values_fill=0
  ) %>%
  mutate(min=min(H,F)) %>%
  select(profession, min)

data %>% inner_join(y=agg, by="profession") %>%
  filter(min>=2)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's clever. However, I applied it on my data and there are some professions for which there are eg. no females, but still show up after the filtering. So my aim is just to have professions with both females and males in that minimum amount. I guess the script fails because of the nonexistence of that level for that profession.

Comment: You're right, I edited my answer to take into account this case.

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted another answer because it was more concise. I appreciate yours too.

Comment: Yet, my answer is more general because you do not need to hardcode the levels of the sex variable :).

Comment: I was looking for the same. Could you explain what you mean by not needing to hardcode the levels?